# jQuery Ajax Joomla 2.5 get from external url

Tags: ajax, jquery, joomla

I'm trying to get a response from controller in external url http://www.site-external.com/index.php?option=com_name&task=get_function&format=json

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType : 'html',
url: "http://www.site-external.com/index.php?option=com_name&task=get_function&format=json",
success: function(response){

    }

});
```

thanks

Comment: you mean `jQuery.ajax`?

Comment: What is the problem you are having, or the help you need?

Comment: if I make a get in the same url "index.php?option=com_name&task=get_function&format=json" Work !!! not in esxternal "http://www.site-external.com/index.php?option=com_name&task=get_function&format=json"

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to get a response from external url

You have a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem. Ajax can't access domains other than the one that the current page resides on.

Possible solutions:

- Proxy the request through a server side script on the local domain.
- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType : 'html',
url: "http://www.site-external.com/component/com_name/controller/your_filename.php",
data: "data=" + datavalue,
success: function(response){    
}
});
```